# SenchaTouch onItemDisclosure

Tags: javascript, html, sencha-touch

my question is how do I open a external HTML page in SenchaTouch when I click at the ItemDisclosure?

This is my Code:

```
if(subListContainerID){
    var that = this;
    onItemDisclosure = function(){
        that.extApplication.views.viewport.setActiveItem(
            SenchaTantorController.extApplication.views[subListContainerID], {
            type: 'slide',
            direction: 'left' 
        });
    }
}else{
    onItemDisclosure = function(){
        alert('!no item to diclose');
    }
}
```

In the *else* it should open the external html page.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why can't You use the javascript code                                       window.location.href = 'http://yourURL/index.html'; inside the onItemDisclosure function()  . It will open the specified file in external browser. If you want it inside the app , you can use child browser plugin for phonegap.

Comment: Happy to hear dat... Gimme some points man. I will add it as an answer...  (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't You use the javascript code

```
 window.location.href = 'yourURL/index.html';
```

inside the onItemDisclosure function() . It will open the specified file in external browser. If you want it inside the app , you can use child browser plugin for phonegap.